# CakePHP 1.3 code to create Html <link> tag

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to create a link tag like

> `<link rel="next" href="localhost/site/posts/index" />`

by cakephp 1.3 code. I need to put it in the head section, but defining it from view

I have tried using $html->meta(), like $html->meta("some title", "localhost/site/posts/index", array('inline' => false, 'rel' => 'next') ) , but  I get

> `<link title="some title" rel="next" type="application/rss+xml" href="localhost/site/posts/index">`

, and if I try to get rid of type or change it I get only the following `<meta rel="next">`,
I have tried also by $html->css(), but I can not remove/change type="text/css" part

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the parameters as an array, that way most of the auto-magic will be skipped, and the second parameter will act as inline option:

```
$html->meta(array('rel' => 'next', 'link' => 'localhost/site/posts/index'), false);
```

Just tested with CakePHP 1.3.15